# Manifolds, isolated singularities, open map

Tags: manifolds, singularity-theory

I can't figure out how to solve the following question:

1) Let $M$ and $N$ be $C^k$-manifolds, such that $\dim M = \dim N = n>1$, and let $f:M\rightarrow N$ be a $C^k$-function. Show that if the singularities of $M$ are isolated, then $f$ is an open map.

Remark: I've tried to use without sucess the Inverse Function Theorem and Sard's Theorem.

Thank you for your attention

Comment: These two questions are unrelated. You should post 1) and 2) each as their own question; you are more likely to get an answer that way.

Comment: Sorry, I am new here. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1897536/a-real-function-such-that-all-singularities-are-isolated-is-an-open-application